# Why does Webpack 2 still bundle without Entry?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

In the webpack 2 config files, I purposely left out the [entry](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) in the config object. Why is it still bundling as before? Is there some kind of default?

Comment: I don't think there is any cache involved when webpack runs. Hate to ask this dumb question, but are you sure the config changes are saved and you are running webpack in the intended folder ?

Comment: I know my script is running from that config file, since changing it will affect things. Yeah it's saved.

Comment: Hmmm. Which version of webpack you are using ? For me, with webpack@3.8.1, i get following error when `entry` is not configured : 

**Configuration file found but no entry configured.
Use --help to display the CLI options.**